# TypeScript/tsc module resolution peculiarity

Tags: typescript, tsc

So I have this structure:

```
node_modules/
   @types/express/
   express/
express/index.ts
main.ts
```

in express/index.ts, I had this:

```
import {RequestHandler} from 'express';
```

and it *wouldn't* resolve. I had the same call in main.ts and that import would not resolve either. I finally figured out that it as because I had a *folder named express with an index.ts file in it*. At first I thought it was just JetBrains that was messing up, but tsc at the command line couldn't resolve it either.

This seems like a bug with typescript - I don't see why the resolution algorithm for TS should be different than the node_modules lookup algorithm. **Is this a bug or not?**

Comment: Are you sure `@types/express` has been installed properly? Everything works for me.

Comment: yeah very sure, hmmm